# Working with modern OpenGL on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

Has anyone had any luck with even getting a window launched. I have been trying to get this to work since lion came out. Prior to that I used linux/windows.

All of the modern openGL I have been doing in the past has been using the unofficial glsdk, however getting that to work on the mac is a nightmare. While on windows/linux its just pre make and make, then you're set.

Right now I have built GLFW and glload and then included them into Xcode project (header search path). I get a build error notification when I build it but there is no output in the bottom left. Nothing is  flagged up in the code body as having issues.

The source file is just the simple_glfw file from glsdk. I can add it in if required.

Comment: Try building it from the command line with [`xcodebuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) to see if that shows you the error you can't find?

Comment: Can't understand why this was closed. Mortennobel provided me a perfect answer, my Xcode is now working correctly with my old windows/linux projects. "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did for creating an GLFW project in XCode:

- Build the GLFW (as described in the GLFW usermanual)
- Created a new XCode project (Command Line Tool) with GLFW example.
- In build settings add /usr/local/include (or the include folder of your glfw) to 'Header search path'
- In build phases -> Link with libraries add OpenGL.framework, Cocoa.framework and libglfw.dylib (browse to find this)

I have attached an XCode project that runs a small OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile example. You might need to adjust the location of glfw.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6024335/glfwtest.zip